# Type 1 Error in Statistical Test with non-trivial alternative

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Say you have an experiment involving 100 oranges tracking the probability that an orange is rotten. You test for a probability p and your null hypothesis is p < 0.01 (all oranges coming from a good farm) and your alternative hypothesis is p > 0.99 (all oranges coming from a bad farm).

For a Type 1 Error probability of 0.05, you basically just need more than 2.64 oranges to be rotten to reject the null hypothesis with a 5% chance to be wrong.

Now, since we rejected the null hypothesis, we automatically accept the alternative hypothesis of p > 0.99.

In my opinion, that also seems absurd.

So have I made any mathematical or logic error in the process above?

Comment: If course it's absurd. The cases are not exhaustive. You might as well say $p<0.01$ with the alternative hypothesis being that the moon is made of cheese.

Comment: The real alternative hypothesis is that $p\geq 0.01$.

Comment: so do we just have to accept the fact that with non-trivial alternative hypotheses, we unavoidably get weird results (rejecting something we are sure is not the case with at the same time accepting something more absurd), or is there a way to better phrase/design the experiment?

Comment: This is where my expertise ends. It's obvious why your result is absurd, but fixing it nontrivially is not something I'm familiar with.